# Explain the parent/child row/column relationship for QStandardItem and QStandardItemModel

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qstandarditemmodel

I am trying to use the `QStandardItem` and `QStandardItemModel` to drive a `TreeView` in Qt.

In Qt the typical model to control the `TreeView`, `TableView` & `ListView` includes the concept of rows and columns, but also parent/child relationships.

I find the documentation very confusing, because it seems these are interdependent (e.g. to add a child to a `QStandardItem`, `appendRow()` is used), but nowhere I have found is dedicated to explaining exactly how.

If I had to guess, I would say: "rows are equivalent to children. columns have meaning only within an item itself". Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Qt item model is recursive: each item is a table of items. It is incorrect to say that rows are equivalent to children: each index can have a child, no matter what its row column.

Of course, not all views can handle all models. Specifically, no Qt's built-in views can handle children in columns other than 0. But you certainly could implement a view that does!